# Can you do a formula, then include a nested IF statement?

Tags: excel

I was trying to do a formula to see if I should or not not have a bet on something.

The formula divides two cells, then -1, then multiplies by 100 to get a percentage. If this percentage is greater to or equal to 10, I want it to say bet, if not, I want it to say Don't bet. Here is what I can't get to work now.

```
=IF(SUM((D27/C27)- 1) * 100) >= 10, "BET", "DON'T BET")
```

Comment: Misplaced/missing parens; `=IF((SUM(D27/C27) - 1) * 100 >= 10, "BET", "DON'T BET")`

Comment: Well that is embarrassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula contains an error

`=IF((SUM((D27/C27)- 1) * 100) >= 10, "BET", "DON'T BET")`

```
    ^ You are missing a bracket here.
```